# How to solve this part of deduction of determinant of transformation matrix?

Tags: determinant, tensors

In part of the deduction for the determinant left or right handedness of a transformation matrix the author comes to this:

$$a_{21}a_{31}+a_{22}a_{32}+a_{23}a_{33}=0,\qquad i.e. \quad a_{2k}a_{3k}=0\qquad (4.1)\\
a_{31}a_{11}+a_{32}a_{12}+a_{33}a_{13}=0,\qquad i.e. \quad a_{3k}a_{1k}=0\qquad (4.2)\\
a_{11}a_{21}+a_{12}a_{22}+a_{13}a_{23}=0,\qquad i.e.\quad a_{1k}a_{2k}=0\qquad (4.3)$$

$a_{ij}$ are direction cosines for the transformation of one set of axes $Ox_i$ to another $Ox_i'$ given by the transformation matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}x_1'&x_2'&x_3'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$$so that $\langle x_1\,x_2\rangle=\langle x_2,x_3\rangle =\langle x_1,x_3\rangle =0$. This is shown in (4.2) and (4.3).

And then the author says "*by solving (4.2) and (4.3) for the ratios $a_{11}$, $a_{12}$, $a_{13}$, we obtain:*"

$$\frac{a_{11}}{a_{32}a_{23}-a_{33}a_{22}}=\frac{a_{12}}{a_{33}a_{21}-a_{31}a_{23}}=\frac{a_{13}}{a_{31}a_{22}-a_{32}a_{21}}=-\frac{1}{k}\qquad(5)$$

I can't figure out how the author got from (4.2) and (4.3) to (5)? Anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first set of equations is equivalent to the following matrix relationship:

$$\tag{1}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{pmatrix}}_M \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{21}&a_{31}\\
a_{12}&a_{22}&a_{32}\\
a_{13}&a_{23}&a_{33}\end{pmatrix}}_{M^T} = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}p&0&0\\
0&q&0\\0&0&r\end{pmatrix}}_{diag(p,q,r)} $$

for certain real numbers $p,q,r$.

Let us denote by $M_1,M_2,M_3$ the line vectors of $M$.

The denominators of your second set of equations are the coordinates of the opposite of $M_2 \times M_3$ (their cross product), then :

$$\tag{2}k M_1 = M_2 \times M_3 \ \ \text{(cross product)}$$

The logical connection between (1) and (2) is that the $M_k$s 
constitute an orthogonal basis (not necessarily orthonormal) ; thus one of the vectors is naturaly proportional to the cross product of the 2 others !

**Edit : a different (computational) approach.**

Multiply (4.2) by $a_{22}$,  multiply (4.3) by $a_{32}$ ; then subtract the resulting equations. After cancellation of the common term $a_{12}a_{22}a_{32}$ and convenient factorizations, we get:

$$-a_{11}(a_{31}a_{22} - a_{32}a_{21})+a_{13}(a_{32}a_{23}-a_{33}a_{22})=0$$

which is equivalent to :

$$\tag{3}\frac{a_{11}}{a_{32}a_{23}-a_{33}a_{22}}=\frac{a_{13}}{a_{31}a_{22}-a_{32}a_{21}}$$

Thus, we have obtained the equality of the first and the third ratios in (5).

A similar manipulation on the two first equations will give

$$\tag{4}\frac{a_{11}}{a_{32}a_{23}-a_{33}a_{22}}=\frac{a_{12}}{a_{33}a_{21}-a_{31}a_{23}}$$

Regarding the last ratio, the common value of (3) and (4) can be taken as being $-\dfrac{1}{k}$ for a certain $k$.

Comment: Thanks, see the edit. I just added that the "a" elements are direction cosines, not sure it's going to help though. This is really all that is given by the author.

Comment: Any more thoughts?

Comment: Your answer is fine, but not for the question I asked!

Comment: By the way, why do you mention a determinant in your question ?

Comment: The determinant mention is because these equations are part of a determinant deduction of handedness of axes. But that is not relevant for this little excerpt.

You have not addressed how the author got from 4.2 and 4.3 to 5! What were the manipulations? For instance, how did he obtain $(a_{32}a_{23}-a_{33}a_{22})$ from equations (4.2) and (4.3)?

Comment: I have written down the second solution.

Comment: To answer your last question : I thought at first that the solution was by a combination of lines of course ; then I had a thorough look at the missing elements and $a_{22}$ was one of them. Besides, I have erased some parts of our discussion that have no longer interest, especialy for future readers...

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't have guessed it. Just curious... did you know what to do in advance or did you have to crack that somehow? I mean, how did you know that we had to multiply by a22
and a32 and not any other element? Maybe I'm just very noob but it doesn't seem obvious to me.